# Problems installation firebase-admin (window 10 an Linux plataform)

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am trying to work with firebase cloudfunctions, my problem is when I prepare the work environment, for which I follow the steps indicated, about node.js version 6.14.0 I try to acturalize both the firebase-tools @ latest and firebase-admin @ latest , when I do this, I get an error, which I transcribe, before I would like to comment on the fact that I made it on Linux environment with ubunto like windows 10
Change versions of node and firebase-admin repeating the same error
Try install the last version node-pre-gyp and repeat the same error

This is my log when I try to perform the installation of both firebase-admin and firebase-tools

Someone could help me

Log

```
npm -g install firebase-tools@latest firebase-admin@latest 
/home/armando/.nvm/versions/node/v6.14.0/bin/firebase -> /home/armando/.nvm/versions/node/v6.14.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/bin/firebase

> grpc@1.12.4 install /home/armando/.nvm/versions/node/v6.14.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp ERR! Completion callback never invoked! 
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-23-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/home/armando/.nvm/versions/node/v6.14.0/bin/node" "/home/armando/.nvm/versions/node/v6.14.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/armando/.nvm/versions/node/v6.14.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v6.14.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-pre-gyp`.
node-pre-gyp ERR! Try to update node-pre-gyp and file an issue if it does not help:
node-pre-gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues>
/home/armando/.nvm/versions/node/v6.14.0/lib
└── firebase-tools@3.19.0 

npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-23-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/armando/.nvm/versions/node/v6.14.0/bin/node" "/home/armando/.nvm/versions/node/v6.14.0/bin/npm" "-g" "install" "firebase-tools@latest" "firebase-admin@latest"
npm ERR! node v6.14.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! grpc@1.12.4 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 6
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.12.4 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the grpc package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs grpc
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls grpc
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/armando/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: On common platforms, GRPC uses pre-built binaries to avoid compilation on the clients. These binaries are fetched via `node-pre-gyp`. It looks like this is not working for you. Can you make sure that you have access to these prebuilts?  You can for example try to get the latest prebuilt for Darwin: https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.12.4/node-v57-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz

Comment: Please also see: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/15507. The resolution there was to disable Kaspersky antivirus.